# PHP request blob file from Azure Container

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm creating a website that needs to be able to retrieve files from an Azure Storage Container that I have and I'm having difficulty actually retrieving any files.

So the container's Access Policy is set to the `Private (no anonymous access)` value since I don't want just anyone to be able to access it. I then went into CORS settings and created a new CORS rule. For now I setup the options as follows:

```
ALLOWED ORIGINS == *
ALLOWED METHODS == GET
ALLOWED HEADERS == *
EXPOSED HEADERS == *
MAX AGE == 10000
```

I think I'm supposed to put my website into the `ALLOWED ORIGINS` field to restrict access to only my website, but for now I'm leaving it just with an `*` to get this started.

So I think this should allow me to `get` blobs from my container...

Here is how I'm attempting to retrieve the files in PHP

```
$response = file_get_contents("https://<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<containername>/SomeSimpleFile.txt");
print_r($response );
```

But I don't get the contents of the file back, instead I get the following error messages:

```
[01-Aug-2018 12:58:35 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<containername>/SomeSimpleFile.txt): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 The specified resource does not exist.
in D:\home\site\wwwroot\index.php on line 30
```

If I go back into the Azure Portal and change the container's access policy to `Blob (anonymous read access for blobs only)` then I am able to get the file using the above PHP code. So I know the url I'm using for the file is correct. It seems I have set something wrong in the CORS settings. Or maybe it's something else.

Any help I can get on this is appreciated.

Comment: Are you setting the request Headers correctly? Basically if it is a private blob then you need Authorizarion Header I guess.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob

Comment: It would appear that I am not... I found this on the header stuff looks like I have some more steps to take https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by visiting a private blob using its plain URL.

You could use [shared access signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1#what-is-a-shared-access-signature). With a SAS, you can grant clients access to resources in your storage account.

Go to portal, your storage account, locate the blob in container. Right click on the blob, select `Generate SAS`. You may see content below.

[image]

You can set the permission, expiration, IP allowed, etc. Then `Generate blob SAS token and URL`, replace your blob url with Blob SAS URL and things should work.

Comment: wow that's so much easier than figuring out all of the header stuff. Instead of creating a SAS for a single file I ended up creating a SAS for the entire container and I'm able to use that with all of the blobs. I can even use it for listing operations too. Thanks!